# Best way for custom button on UITabBar to presents modal view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Xcode/Swift. I have a center button I want to present a modal view from the current view (tab).

I've implemented a custom class for UITabBar that adds that button according to this [guide](https://equaleyes.com/blog/2017/09/04/the-common-raised-center-button-problems-in-tabbar/).

This UITabBar has no view controller in self that I can find, so I get an error when I try to present a view.
`Error: Value of type 'MainTabBar' has no member 'present'`

**Is there a way I can have this button present modal from the current view?** 
I'm not sure how to reach the current view from this custom class.

**Should I point the button's addTarget to a [uitabbar Delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbardelegate?changes=_7) and watch for it in my other views?**

**Should I stop doing this and just do tabs with a tab that pulls up my modal view in a ViewDidAppear() on a different view?** 
I think I lose the ability to pop, or dismiss, back to the last view if I do that.

Here's the custom UITabBar class I'm working with.

```
class MainTabBar: UITabBar {

private var middleButton = UIButton()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setupMiddleButton()
}

func setupMiddleButton() {
    middleButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 70, height: 70)
    middleButton.backgroundColor = .blue
    middleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    middleButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
    middleButton.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: 0)
    middleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(test), for: .touchUpInside)
    addSubview(middleButton)
}

@objc func test() {
    let vc = createController()
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

Comment: Figured it out. Writing my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found a better [implementation](http://%20https://github.com/drrost/Custom-Tabbar-Cetner-Button). 
Created a custom class inherited from UITabBarController and named it MainViewController.

Setup the middle button in that controller instead of in the MainTabBar custom class.

self now has member present.

```
  @objc func test() {
     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc =
    storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "createModal") as! createController

    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

https://github.com/drrost/Custom-Tabbar-Cetner-Button